# for loop in list.files function produces result only for the last i (R)

Tags: r, csv, for-loop, read.table

I have a directory that contains lets say two `.csv` files, that i want to read and import into R.

So far i have tried the code below that actually works. But only for one of the files.

```
for (i in list.files(path = ".", pattern = "\\.csv$")){
    print(i)
    f <- read.table(i, fill=TRUE, row.names=NULL)
    Table <- data.frame(f[3])
    Table["station.id"] <- i
}
Table
```

Produces

```
      V3 station.id
1   8.27  agrin.csv
2   9.11  agrin.csv
3  11.60  agrin.csv
4  15.30  agrin.csv
5  20.53  agrin.csv
6  25.07  agrin.csv
7  27.42  agrin.csv
8  27.11  agrin.csv
9  22.92  agrin.csv
10 17.98  agrin.csv
11 13.15  agrin.csv
12  9.62  agrin.csv
13 17.34  agrin.csv
```

What i want is to implement a `for` loop that will iterate the dir and create a table as shown above for each file inside.

Notice that `print(i)` line gives back two results `agrin.csv` and `agr.csv` for example

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before the `for` loop, let:

```
 Table <- data.frame(V3=numeric(0), station.id=character(0))
```

This is called object *preallocation*.
Then, in the loop, try playing with `rbind`.
With this scheme you'll be creating your object *incrementally*.

Comment: why is it important to set a table before loop starts?

Comment: Otherwise you'll be working on a new object in each loop iteration. And here you'd like to "continue" your computations on an existing object. In other words, you are creating `Table` incrementally, adding more data in each iter.

Answer (score 0):

You are not specifying the row index of `Table$station.id` so the last value ends up being written over the whole column. Try this:

```
file.names <- list.files(path = ".", pattern = "\\.csv$")
Table <- data.frame(V3=rep(NA, length(file.names)), 
                    station.id=rep(NA, length(file.names)))
for (i in seq_along(file.names)){
    print(file.names[i])
    f <- read.table(file.names[i], fill=TRUE, row.names=NULL)
    Table[i, "V3"] <- f[3]     ## this only works if f has only one observation.
    Table[i, "station.id"] <- file.names[i]
}
Table
```

Comment: Correct to: `for (i in seq_along(file.names))`

Comment: is `req_along` part of some package? I am getting `could not find function req_along`.

Comment: That would be my personal implementation of `seq_along()`. Modified the reply to use the official version :-)

Comment: Have you removed the `Table <- data.frame(..)` definition from the loop body? You are rewriting the data on each iteration.

Comment: Now i am lost. please update the answer so we can have a common ground to talk :)

Comment: I fixed the code. I had missed the part where you rewrite the whole data in each iteration. Make sure the assignment to the first column is correct.

Comment: There is something wrong with your code. please review it and let me know what's up

Comment: What exactly is in the data files, and what part of it would you write in the first column of `Table`? Your example is incomplete.